# Is there a way to get a virtual Fn key to work on a virtual keyboard? (Not a toggle Fn key so not like what the default on-screen keyboard does)

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, fn-key, on-screen-keyboard

Is there a way to get a virtual <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to work on a virtual keyboard? (Not a toggle <kbd>Fn</kbd> key so not like what the default on-screen keyboard)

For example, the keyboard on my laptop has a key that says <kbd>Fn</kbd>, and if let's say I open notepad and hit <kbd>F6</kbd> then nothing happens, or if in chrome I hit <kbd>F6</kbd> then it shifts focus around. It's not a hotkey just a regular <kbd>F6</kbd> key.

but there are also some keys that can perform another function, for example if I do <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>, then a volume control comes up. There's a key that says "home" and it says "prt sc" in a little box. If I fold <kbd>Fn</kbd> and tap that key, then it does a print screen. otherwise it does 'home'.

So my keyboard has an <kbd>Fn</kbd> key that lets me access some other mode for a key.

I would like to be able to use this from an on-screen keyboard (this would also be useful if I was connecting via teamviewer). Let's say I want to enter <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>.

I can't see a way to do that from a virtual keyboard.

The on-screen keyboard that comes with win7 and win10, has an <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, but it's a key that toggles between the top row of the virtual keyboard being function keys, and being numeric keys.  That's not the kind of <kbd>Fn</kbd> key that i'm looking for.

I'm looking for a virtual keyboard that can emulate as if the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key has been held on the keyboard.

Comment: The trouble with those keys is they are combined before leaving the keyboard, they're not done in the OS. The OS doesn't even see those 'volume up/down' type keys at all, they're acted on before the interpreter even sees them. I can demonstrate this for Mac using an on-screen key-code interpreter, but idk how to show it for Win.

Comment: @Tetsujin what program would you use for the mac case, as an on-screen key-code interpreter. (so I see what you mean), as I have a mac laptop I can test it on to see what you mean.

Comment: Sure - [Key Codes](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) freeware. You can see the Fn press & the 'regular' F-keys, but the volume, brightness etc just kind of vanish into the ether & are not seen.[Xcode can do all this too, but it's a bit weighty just for this one test]